# Change python's print behaviour in a context

Tags: python

I would like (just for debugging purposes) being able to change how the print works in a context

```
def printing_foo(a):
    print(a)
    return a

print("{")
with print_prefix(" " * 4):
    list(map(printing_foo, range(4)))
print("}")
```

would produce:

```
{
    0
    1
    2
    3
}
```

much like you can have a local context for decimals.

or do I have to write my own context sensitive print and import and use it in all modules?

Comment: I used a little bit of both in my head, thanks for the remark

Comment: `lambda` could replace `printing_foo`.

Comment: no it cannot both ``print`` and ``return a``, it was just illustrative purposes only. In python3 you could just do ``list(map(print, range(4)))``, if not considering the ``return a`` as you would with an lambda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a context manager to capture `sys.stdout`, then prefix anything `print()` writes to it:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys

class Prefixer(object):
    def __init__(self, prefix, orig):
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.orig = orig
    def write(self, text):
        self.orig.write(self.prefix + text)
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.orig, attr)     

@contextmanager
def prefix_stdout(prefix):
    current_out = sys.stdout
    try:
        sys.stdout = Prefixer(prefix, current_out)
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = current_out
```

and use as:

```
with prefix_stdout('Prefixed: '):
    print('Hello world!')
```

but take into account that `print()` calls usually write data to `stdout` in separate chunks; the newline at the end is a *separate* write.

Comment: really cool solution, is there any documentation on how python chunks up the write? Is it mostly just the trailing newline? in that case one just make an exception for when text is just a newline right?

Comment: No, how `print()` writes to `stdout` is entirely up to the implementation. I'd experiment a little with under what circumstances newlines are written and adjust the context manager for that.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging I would recommend the logging module.

Comment: sure, but it misses the main point, I'm currently working a lot with contexts and the only way to get a grip on what is happening is by having different indentations (for the eye, different logging levels will not suffice) levels or alike. Is this possible to have a context aware logging with indentations or something like it?

Comment: Just use the logging.getLogger, this way you can get an automatic prefix on all statements. I personally use logging.getLogger(__name__), this way I get logging from each module. But you can add your own or a mix : logging.getLogger(__name__ + "_ImportantSubpart")